# PHP multi-byte alternatives UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8, multibyte-functions

I've been searching for UTF8-safe alternatives for string manipulation functions. I've found many different opinions and suggestions. I would like to ask if following functions can cause problems in UTF-8 and if does, what should I use instead. I know the list of mb_ prefixed functions in PHP manual, but there are not all functions I am using.

Functions are: implode, explode, str_replace, preg_match, preg_replace

Thank you

Comment: `preg_` family of functions work fine with unicode, but you'll need to specify in the parameters that you're using unicodes in the string.

Comment: @AleksG thanks for responding. Do you know also what with implode, explode and str_replace?

Comment: Those are UTF-8 safe, provided everything is valid UTF-8. No valid UTF-8 byte sequence is a sub-bytestring of some other UTF-8 byte sequence.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652261/str-word-count-alternative-for-utf8

Answer (score 6):

`explode` just looks for an identical byte sequence and separates the string at that point. Since UTF-8 is safely backwards compatible with ASCII, there's no concern and it will work fine. `implode` just assembles strings together, which works fine as well due to the properties of UTF-8. `str_replace` works for the same reasons. The `preg_` functions work fine as long as you are using the [`/u` modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to safely manipulate with UTF8 characters, you can do it like this:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
preg_replace( '`...`u', '...', $string ) // with the u (unicode) modifier
```

Comment: `mb_internal_encoding` is only useful for `mb_` functions. It has nothing to do with the `preg_` functions.