# How can I split a string into three word chunks?

Tags: php, arrays, split

I need to split a string in every three words using PHP

`"This is an example of what I need."`

The output would be:

```
This is an
is an example
an example of
example of what
of what I
what I need
```

I have this example with Java

```
String myString = "This is an example of what I need.";
        String[] words = myString.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String threeWords;
              if (i == words.length - 1)
                  threeWords = words[i]; 
              else if(i == words.length - 2)
                  threeWords = words[i] + " " + words[i + 1]; 
              else 
                  threeWords = words[i] + " " + words[i + 1] + " " + words[i + 2];
              System.out.println(threeWords);
    }
```

Comment: @moonn86 what is the desired output when the word count is not divisible by 3?  What if there aren't 3 words?

Comment: the data you need is called trigrams. (ngrams for the general n-word case). Should help you google for a solution

Comment: @mick, the trigrams are overlapping

Comment: @alexis yes, I see the overlap, but first trigram is omitted.  We don't know what is desired when the word count is not divisible by 3.  This question lacks a comprehensive [mcve], a php coding attempt, and proof of research.  It should be closed as Needs Clarity.

Comment: the first trigram is omitted by mistake, you can see that from the java code. Yeah the question is unclear and low-effort, but from a new user.

Comment: Do you need all punctuation to be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that use explode, [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and implode.

```
$example = 'This is an example of what I need.';

$arr = explode(" ",$example);
foreach($arr as $key => $word){
  //if($key == 0) continue;
  $subArr = array_slice($arr,$key,3);
  if(count($subArr) < 3) break;
  echo implode(" ",$subArr)."<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
This is an
is an example
an example of
example of what
of what I
what I need.
```

If you want to suppress the first output with This, remove the comment in the line

```
//if($key == 0) continue;
```

If the example can have less than 3 words and these should be output then the line with the break must be as follows:

```
if(count($subArr) < 3 AND $key != 0) break;
```

For strings that are not only separated by single spaces, [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php) is recommended. Example:

```
$example = "This  is an example of what I need.
 Sentence,containing a comma and Raphaël.";

$arr = preg_split('/[ .,;\r\n\t]+/u', $example, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach($arr as $key => $word){
  $subArr = array_slice($arr,$key,3);
  if(count($subArr) < 3) break;
  echo implode(" ",$subArr)."<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
This is an
is an example
an example of
example of what
of what I
what I need
I need Sentence
need Sentence containing
Sentence containing a
containing a comma
a comma and
comma and Raphaël
```

Comment: As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21713214/2943403), `\s` is more brief to use inside the character class.  Your pattern will not isolate quote-wrapped, parenthetical, etc words.

Answer (score 0):

To include only words (notice the fullstop is removed from the last trigram), use `str_word_count()` to form the array of strings.

Then you need to loop while there are three elements to print.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4IWGC))

```
$example = 'This is an example of what I need.';

$words = str_word_count($example, 1);
for ($x = 0; isset($words[$x + 2]); ++$x) {
    printf("%s %s %s\n", $words[$x], $words[$x + 1], $words[$x + 2]);
}
```

Output:

```
This is an
is an example
an example of
example of what
of what I
what I need
```

If you don't like `printf()`, you could `echo implode(' ', [the three elements])`.

If you want to print a single string of words when there are less than 3 total words in the string, then you could use a post-test loop. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/K789X)

And then, of course, if we going to stumble down the rocky road of "what is a word", then an ironclad definition of "what is a word" will need to be defined and then a regex (potentially with multibyte support) will need to be suitably crafted. [Basic Demo](https://3v4l.org/JCaSH)

Comment: Note that str_word_count does not support multibyte characters. If the text contains words like Raphaël, it becomes Rapha l (2 words!)

Comment: There are work arounds for this fringe case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19274144/2943403 `str_word_count()` does remove the punctuation at the end of the sentence though. :)